# What is the exact role of the integrals in a PID Controller?

Tags: calculus, integration, applications

I am trying to understand the function of a [PID Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).

It returns a value, which is the sum of three components. The proportional, derivative and integral components. I am having issues grasping the usage of the integral component.

I *know* what an integral is. Integration is, in this case, the accumulation of the errors captured by the controller. In other words, in every iteration the current error is added to some variable, which is then multiplied by some constant and added to the result.

However, I fail to see how is such accumulation practically helpful. I mean, its actual role in the formula.

I have seen several pages. All of them mention the same thing: it eliminates some "offset". I'm afraid I don't know what this "offset" means and, more importantly, how does it eliminate it **exactly**. For example, I understand very well the role of the derivative, as you can get the previous instant rate of change which allows you to attempt to predict the future error.

I was hoping this was the right place to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the coefficients of PID controller has a zone of responsibility. The differential coefficient reacts to attempts to shake the controller, a proportional - defines a linear step response of the input parameter. "Integral" eliminates accumulation of errors.

Tuning the PID is conducted in the above order. Ie, tuning the "integral" is conducted after the other factors.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to see what happens is to use only $K_p$ (proportional gain).
The Error will get multiplied by a constant and sent as an output of the controller to the actuator:

$PID_{output}=K_p*Error$

As the Feedback matches the Setpoint, the actuator will reduce its output, ironically this creates the "steady state error", error cannot reach zero.  An easy way to visualize this is that if the Error approaches zero, the actuator output will also approach zero.

To eliminate the steady state error, you activate the integral part of the PID and this helps maintaining the actuator output level when error approaches zero.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked with PID controllers in the application of gas chromotography.  the integral function of PID control feedback mechanism is akin to your "tare" function in a weighing machine.  When you go to a counter in a store, you measure your purchases (eg, food items), that guy at the counter presses tare button to bring the meter read "0" offsetting the error of not only the previous measurement but also all the positive and negative errors it had accumulated over the past measurements.  If the dust keeps accumulating on the weighing pan, the measurements gets adjusted strongly to subtract the weight of the dust.  Similarly, in a PID controller, the offset is nothing but to get the process shoot to the baseline by reacting strongly ( by a stronger feedback to in-control process by adjusting to the errors of all the past measurements summed up (both negative and positive errors). This was my understanding of the integral component of the PID controller.  I hope this answers your question.

Comment: or in four words: eliminating steady state error

Answer (score 0):

A PID (Proportional-Integral-Derivative) controller is a commonly used control algorithm in control systems. It adjusts the output of a system based on the error between a desired setpoint and the measured process variable. The three components of a PID controller are:

Proportional (P) Control:
The proportional component produces an output that is proportional to the current error. It is determined by multiplying the error by a constant gain factor known as the proportional gain (Kp). The output of the proportional term is given by P = Kp * error, where error is the difference between the desired setpoint and the measured process variable. The proportional control provides a response that is directly proportional to the magnitude of the error, but it does not consider the history of the error.

Integral (I) Control:
The integral component considers the accumulation of past errors and produces an output based on the integral of the error over time. It helps in eliminating steady-state errors and provides a long-term correction. The integral term is determined by multiplying the integral gain (Ki) with the integrated error over time. The output of the integral term is given by I = Ki * ∫(error dt), where ∫(error dt) represents the integral of the error over time. The integral control responds to both the magnitude and duration of the error.

Derivative (D) Control:
The derivative component considers the rate of change of the error and produces an output based on the rate of change. It helps in predicting the future behavior of the error and provides a quick response to changes. The derivative term is determined by multiplying the derivative gain (Kd) with the rate of change of the error. The output of the derivative term is given by D = Kd * d(error)/dt, where d(error)/dt represents the derivative of the error with respect to time. The derivative control responds to the rate of change of the error.

The final output of the PID controller is the sum of the proportional, integral, and derivative components:

Output = P + I + D

The gains (Kp, Ki, and Kd) of the PID controller are typically adjusted or tuned to achieve the desired control performance, such as stability, fast response, and minimal overshoot. The tuning process involves iteratively adjusting the gains based on the system's behavior and desired response.

For more information on the PID controller s please [click here](https://www.theclimatictester.com/post/understanding-pid-controllers-what-they-are-how-they-work-and-how-to-tune-them)